# selenium C# Unable to locate element

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, xpath

I am having a trouble with Selenium. I am trying to open Google and search `Selenium`. Then to open the first page that appear, so I am doing this:

`driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*@id=\"rso\"]/div/div/div[1]/div/h3/a")).Click();`

But it doesn't open the first url by XPath. It says: `Unable to locate element`
Can you help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax for the xpath is wrong, after * symbol there should be a square bracket.

Relative xpath: (//div[@id='ires']//div[@class='srg']//h3[@class='r']/a)[1]

Relative xpath is recommended because if html of the page gets change then absolute xpath will fails

Before clicking the element provide Explicit wait.

```
  WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
  wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("(//div[@id='ires']//div[@class='srg']//h3[@class='r']/a)[1]"))).Click();
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: It did! Thank you very much...I try also with explicit wait and implicit wait but it didn't work. Your way is perfect. Thank you again!!!

Comment: @Akarsh, This  above answer will not work when your `html` gets changed, so as per my opinion you should use `relative xpath`, not an `absolute xpath`.

Comment: @JainishKapadia Updated answer with relative xpath. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try to wait until link is generated and clickable:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class=\"rc\"]/h3/a"))).Click();
```